# Get value of XML parent/ancestor using Xpath and PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, parent, siblings

Let's say I have this XML:

```
<Routes>
  <Route ref="timeconditions">
   <Table>
     <Tablename>timeconditions</Tablename>
     <Fields>
       <Fieldsname>truegoto</Fieldsname>
     </Fields>
   </Table>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

PHP:

```
$doc    = new SimpleXMLElement('routingConfig.xml', null, true);
$foo = $doc->xpath('/Routes/Route[@ref="timeconditions"]/Table/Fields[@Fieldsname="truegoto"]/ancestor::Tablename');
print_r($foo);
```

Returns blank array. Now I realize I'm basically digging into a child then backing up to it's parent, but in my context that is what I need to do. What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to get `<Fieldsname>falsegoto</Fieldsname>` parents sibling value called `<Tablename>`.

Going crosseyed staring at this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fields` has no attribute `Fieldsname` its a child node, also `Tablename` is a sibling of `Fields` not an ancestor. Try

```
$foo = $doc->xpath('/Routes/Route[@ref="timeconditions"]/Table/Fields[Fieldsname="truegoto"]/preceding-sibling::Tablename');
```

Comment: Thank you very much - always a simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
/*/*/Table[Fields/Fieldsname = 'truegoto']/Tablename
```

This selects any `Tablename` element that is a child of any `Table` element that has a grandchild (whose parent is `Fields`) `Fieldsname` whose string value is `'truegoto'`, and that (the `Table` element) is a grandchild of the top element of the XML document.

**Do note**:

1. No reverse axes are used.
2. Because of this, the expression is shorter, simpler and easier to understand.